# ASP.NET binding a data source using WHERE based on DropDownList control Selected Value

Tags: asp.net

I have one drop down list ( called nodeDropDownList ) that queries a database table.

The database table "Nodes" has this data:

```
id | name
------------
0  | Node1
1  | Node2
2  | Node3
```

The drop down list is bound to a data source ( data source A) which just gets this list of stuff from the DB. The Data field to display is "name" and the data field value is "id".

There is a second table "Pipes" which looks like this:

```
pipeid | pipename | nodeid
----------------------------
0      | pipe1    | 0
1      | pipe2    | 0
2      | pipe3    | 1
3      | pipe4    | 2
```

As you can see, one node can have multiple pipes.

There is a second drop down list, which is bound to a different data source ( data source B ). It's has a data field display of "pipename" and a data field value of "pipeid".

Typically a user would firstly select a node. Upon postback the second drop down list would

Within the configuration of this data source it selects all of the "pipes" from the database where the nodeid is that of the previously selected dropdownlist. it does this via a WHERE expression. I have set the WHERE expression up like this:

```
Column: nodeid
Operator: ==
Source : Control
ControlId: nodeDropDownList
```

The preview windows shows:

```
Expression            |  Value
nodeid == @nodeid     |   nodeDropDownList.SelectedValue
```

When I try to run the query, it complains that type (Int) is not comparable to type (Object). This is because the nodeDropDownList.SelectedValue does not have a predefined value.

My questions is, is there any way to specify or cast this SelectedValue to a (Int) so that my data source can bind and compare with it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using in asp.net?

Comment: This is a simplified example. Actually copying and pasting code would probably not help matters. You should be able to gain all the information you need from what I have provided. The actual code uses different variable names and more complex tables.